# Не могу подключится к bootstrap и css по не дефолтным маршрутам

Tags: php

фреймворк написан на php:
При дефолтном маршруте http://localhost/fwloc/ на регулярном выражении $Rut->add("^$",array('controller'=>'Main','action'=>'index'));скрипт и css файл подключаются http://localhost/fwloc/css/main.css.Как только ввожу не дефолтный маршрут localhost/fwloc/page/about  регвыражен $Rut->add("^page/(?P[a-z-]+)$",array('controller'=>'Page','action'=>'view')); скрипт и css файл не подключаются view-source:http://localhost/fwloc/page/css/main.css получается что page как бы нарушает путь к скрипту,по этому пути скрипта там нет.
Вот файл .htaccess который находится в корне проекта с таким перенаправлением:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

A вот файл .htaccess который находится в папке public из которого запускается проект с таким перенаправлением: 

      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

как решить проблему что бы не дефолтные пути маршрутов которые я ввожу в адресную строку не портили путь к скриптам?топчусь уже 2-ой день

Comment: Покажите как и где Вы подключаете сам CSS файл

Comment: путь к CSS и JS начинайте от корня сайта `/..`

Answer (score 0):

Всё получилось, просто надо было прописать путь к моим скриптам от самого корня моего проекта; он у меня лежит в `localhost`, я прописал так:

```
/fwloc/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

а было:

```
bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

всем спасибо, кто откликнулся на мою проблему (уже решена).